# Modal without rounded corners?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to create an Modal in iOS without rounded corners - the Modal represents an UIViewController in an UINavigationController.

When ill try with:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
}
```

It is not working. Is there a solution for that?

Edit: I mean that rounded corners here:

[image]

That code is only an example (removed all other useless code here)

Comment: Where are the rounded corners coming from? Usually, you should not have them. Could you maybe provide more details about you app. BTW, in the `viewWillAppear` method you should always call `super. viewWillAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Already found a solution. Assign a class to your modal view and add:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
   view.superview?.layer.cornerRadius  = 0.0
}
```

This will remove the rounded corners.

Comment: Setting `superview.layer.cornerRadius` to 0 is the key part. Setting `mastToBounds = false` wasn't necessary for me

Comment: Weirdly, this only takes the corner radius off my bottom corners...

Comment: @tarrball , for me it only applies to the top right corner..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
navController?.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
```